# $\sum_{k=0}^{3^n-1}\binom{2k}{k}$ is divisible by $3^n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Prove that the sum $$\sum_{k=0}^{3^n-1}\binom{2k}{k}$$ is divisible by $3^n$.
 Use by Vandermonde's Identity. So
$$\binom{2k}{k}
=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}^2 $$.

Any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please improve the title, tell us what $a$ is and show your attempts.

Comment: After a little numerical experiment, it seems that it's precisely divisible by $3^{2n}$

Comment: Also, Mathematica gives $\sum _{k=0}^n \binom{2 k}{k}=-\binom{2 (n+1)}{n+1} \, _2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{3}{2};n+2;4\right)-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: @ MaudPieTheRocktorate How this identity divided by $3^{2n}$?

Comment: I asked Mathematica to calculate Table[IntegerExponent[Sum[Binomial[2*k, k], {k, 0, 3^n - 1}], 3], {n, 0, 9}] and it returned {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18}

Comment: Also, $\frac{1}{3^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^{3^n-1}\binom{2k}{k}\equiv 1 \mod 9$, $\frac{1}{3^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^{3^n-1}\binom{2(3^n + k)}{3^n + k}\equiv 2 \mod 9$, $\frac{1}{3^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^{3^n-1}\binom{2(2\cdot 3^n + k)}{2\cdot 3^n + k}\equiv 6 \mod 9$

Comment: @  MaudPieTheRocktorate Do you have any proof for your claim?

Comment: Everything becomes simple if you are able to spot a hidden cyclotomic polynomial, namely $\Phi_6(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\binom{2k}{k}=[x^0](x+x^{-1})^{2k}$ we have that

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{3^n-1}\binom{2k}{k} = [x^0]\sum_{k=0}^{3^n-1}(x+x^{-1})^k = [x^0]\frac{(x+x^{-1})^{3^n}-1}{(x+x^{-1})-1}=\text{Res}\left(\frac{(z+z^{-1})^{3^n}-1}{z^2-z+1},z=0\right)$$
but actually $\text{Res}\left(\frac{z^m}{z^2-z+1},z=0\right)$ has a pretty simple behaviour. It equals zero for any non-negative integer $m$ and for every $m\in3\mathbb{Z}$, $1$ for every negative $m\in 6\mathbb{Z}+\{4,5\}$ and $-1$ for every negative $m\in 6\mathbb{Z}+\{1,2\}$. You may draw interesting conclusions from expanding $(z+z^{-1})^{3^n}$ through the binomial theorem and considering that $\binom{3^n}{h}$, for any non-negative $h\not\in 3\mathbb{Z}$, is divided by a large power of $3$.